# AJAX and DATATABLES

Tags: jquery, ajax, vb.net, datatables

When i call Ajax request, network request window show that there is an error in the AJAX response.

```
Message:    Primitiva JSON non valida: idParrocchia.
<br>StackTrace in:System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializePrimitiveObject() in System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth) in System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.BasicDeserialize(String input, Int32 depthLimit, JavaScriptSerializer serializer) in System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit) in System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize[T](String input) in System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParamsFromPostRequest(HttpContext context, JavaScriptSerializer serializer) in System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParams(WebServiceMethodData methodData, HttpContext context) in System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)
    ExceptionType   System.ArgumentException
```

The code is

```
"ajax": {
    "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "type": "POST",
    "url": "ajax/WSHome.asmx/GetNewsList",
    "data": {idParrocchia: idParr},
    "dataType": "json",
    'dataSrc': '',
    'cache': false,
    "success": successAjax()
},
```

Thanks,
Luca

Comment: can you add more code ... where are you getting idParr?

Comment: [**success** - Must **not** be overridden as it is used internally in DataTables. To manipulate / transform the data returned by the server use **ajax.dataSrc**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax)

Comment: idParrocchia is a number that the server obtains from the database at login action